# Has anyone used Magma in Pharo2.0?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to get `Magma` working on `Pharo 2.0`. i find that there are lots of issues regarding deprecated `SystemChangeNotifier` etc.I just what to confirm that no one has ever done that.And also i would like to know if its worth trying for.

Comment: I would like to know why i was down voted. Pls leave a comment so i can improve myself...thanks.

Comment: For pharo compatibility, I recommend subscribing to the magma mailing list http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/magma or ask directly to the author... Whether it's worth or not, I can't tell

Comment: Maybe the downvotes are related to this rule : don't ask "Product or service recommendations or comparisons" http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: But much more likely is just clueless voters. Don't worry, there are lots of them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magma is fully supported on Squeak, but not on Pharo.  I simply don't have time to maintain a Pharo fork of Magma, which is why I'm looking for volunteers from the Pharo community assist with this.

http://forum.world.st/Magma-1-4-on-Pharo-1-4-and-beyond-td4661790.html

A new release of Magma is coming soon for Squeak, but not for Pharo.  The best platform to run the latest Magma is the latest Squeak but if you're determined to run it on Pharo, Magma 1.3 and 1.4 should work well enough on Pharo 1.4 at least for you to gauge whether you'd like to proceed further with making it run on 2.0.

If you have any further questions about Magma, please post them to the Magma mailing list.

Regards,
  Chris Muller

Comment: Thanks a lot.. as a matter of fact..i would definitely like to contribute in the role of the pharo volunteer...if i thats possible...thanks again